# Weird Clusplot when plotting k-mediods clustering vector

Tags: r, clustering, data-visualization, unsupervised-learning, k-medoids

The basic idea of the problem is that I need to cluster a set of points for which I have a dissimilarity matrix.

I have a dataset of around 4600 points (latitudes and longitudes). I have also precomputed the dissimilarity matrix which is nothing but a `timeMatrix` (travel time between all pair of points).

In the time matrix if a point is not reachable to another within a certain time, say 5 minutes, then the value in the matrix corresponding to those points is marked as Long.MAX_VALUE. Otherwise, the time is calculated by querying a Trip Planner API. (So this is just to reduce the number of queries to the API)

I am using `pam` (Partitioning Around Mediods) method in R.

The code that I am using is:

```
kmed <- pam(timeMatrix, 100, diss = TRUE)
```

When I try to visualize this using `clusplot`, I get really weird plots.

```
clusplot(timeMatrix, kmed$cluster, diss=TRUE)
```

The image for this plot is:[image: clusplot output when using timeMatrix]

I also tried passing the dataset of points (`lmks`) into the clusplot function, but I got a similar plot for it as well.

```
clusplot(lmks, kmed$cluster, diss=FALSE)
```

The image for the plot is: [image: clusplot output when using lmks dataset(latitudes and longitudes of the points)]

I request you to please help me understand what is happening and how to deal with it. There are `ellipses` on the points describing the clusters, but I don't know about the `pink colored noise` on the top.

Also, it would be great if you can suggest me about some other clustering method in which I can pass in the `timeMatrix`.

Thanks. Sorry, if this question is trivial, as I am a beginner in cluster analysis and R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with fewer clusters to understand the plot and look at *all* the available parameters such as `lines` to control the drawing of lines.

I don't think this visualization scales up to more than 10 clusters, sorry. It draws one ellipse per cluster (so you get 100 ellipses) and a line inbetween any two clusters (so you get 4950 lines on top).

Also, clusplot may not understand your distance matrix correctly. Since your input data is 2d, it should be able to recover a rotated-mirrored version of the lower image. The two first PCs should explain almost 100% of the variance (only a little curvature is supposedly lost) but it says only 15.13% of the variance are represented? (Update, this is probably due to your abuse of Long.MAX_VALUE)

The problem with `clusplot` is that it tries to do too much automagically. More often than not it is much better if you do things by hand both to have more control and to *understand* what you are plotting. StackExchange is full of questions where people fail to understand what clusplot can do, and when it failed.

Comment: "automagically" is an interesting word

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse for your answer. I have a few doubts. What do you mean by, "recover a rotated-mirrored version of the lower image" and "the two first PCs"? I also don't get when it is said that x% of variance is represented.

Comment: Please see the clusplot documentation on that. Notice the axes labels ("Component 1" etc).